# Why are all modes occuped in a cavity

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermal-radiation

When deriving planks law for blackbody radiation it calculates the density of modes inside the cavity as a function of frequency, assuming that all modes at that frequency are filled. Why is it the case that all the modes must be filled and is that still the case for cavities at a low temperature?